# VB.net inconsistent speed when filling a dataset

Tags: vb.net, dataset, dbase

I have a program that pulls in a bunch of data from a dbase database, does some simple loops and calcs and then graphs the results. I've noticed that the time it takes to complete this seems to vary randomly. I implemented a timer in the code that simply tells me what routine is causing the slow speed. What's strange is that it either takes around 5 seconds from start to finish or about 25 seconds, never in between. According to the timer, the time delay (when it occurs) is when filling a dataset. Note that the process is repeated 5 times total so in reality filling each dataset either takes about .5s each time or about 4.5s.

Things to note:
1) dbase Database is stored on a computer on the network
2) the amount of data that the dataset is being filled with varies quite a bit with no affect on speed. (For example, the last time this occurred, the first loop thru filling the dataset had 134 records and took 4.524s just to fill the dataset, the 5 loop thru had 523 records and took 4.756s.

Any thoughts on what's causing this or better yet how to fix it?

This is literally the code that I being timed:

```
Form1.pCodeTimer.StartProc("DBFillds" & Cnt)
RecordCount = DBda.Fill(DBds, "DB_Data")
Form1.pCodeTimer.EndProc("DBFillds" & Cnt)
```

The first and last lines simple start and stop the timer.

EDIT:
This is the code for the "timer" I'm curious as to why this seems like such a bad way to time the code unless maybe I'm misleading everyone by calling it a "timer".

```
Public Class CodeTimer
Dim Processes As New List(Of MyProcess)
Dim CodeStart As Long

Public Sub StartProc(ProcName As String)
    Dim Proc As MyProcess = New MyProcess(ProcName)
    Processes.Add(Proc)
End Sub
Public Sub EndProc(ProcName As String)
    Dim ProcMatches As New List(Of MyProcess)
    ProcMatches = Processes.FindAll(Function(column) column.ProcName = ProcName)
    If ProcMatches.Count > 1 Then
        'MsgBox("More than one process found that matches the name '" & ProcName & "'.")
    Else
        ProcMatches(0).ProcEnd()
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub StartTimer()
    CodeStart = DateTime.Now.Ticks
End Sub
Public Sub EndTimer()
    Dim strResult As String = ""
    Dim TotalTime As TimeSpan = New TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks - CodeStart)
    For i As Integer = 0 To Processes.Count - 1
        strResult += Processes(i).ProcName & ": " & Processes(i).ElapsedTime.Seconds.ToString & "." & Processes(i).ElapsedTime.Milliseconds.ToString & "s" & vbCrLf
        If Processes(i).ProcDesc <> "" Then
            strResult += Processes(i).ProcDesc & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next
    strResult += "Total Timer Run Time: " & TotalTime.Seconds & "." & TotalTime.Milliseconds.ToString & "s"
    If TotalTime.Seconds > 5 Then
        MsgBox(strResult)
    End If

End Sub
Public Sub AddDesc(ProcName As String, newProcDesc As String)
    Dim ProcMatches As New List(Of MyProcess)
    ProcMatches = Processes.FindAll(Function(column) column.ProcName = ProcName)
    If ProcMatches.Count > 1 Then
        'MsgBox("More than one process found that matches the name '" & ProcName & "'.")
    Else
        ProcMatches(0).ProcDesc = newProcDesc
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

And the Process class that it uses:

```
Public Class MyProcess
Public ProcName As String
Public ProcDesc As String
Public ElapsedTime As TimeSpan
Public StartTime As Long
Public EndTime As Long

Public Sub ProcEnd()
    EndTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks
    ElapsedTime = New TimeSpan(EndTime - StartTime)
End Sub

Public Sub New(newProcName As String, Optional newProcDesc As String = "")
    ProcName = newProcName
    StartTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks
    If newProcDesc <> "" Then
        ProcDesc = newProcDesc
    End If
End Sub 
End Class
```

This is a snippet of the code when the query is run:

```
        pCodeTimer.StartProc("QueryYr" & i)
        SQL = "SELECT J_ASALE as ActSale, J_PSALE as ProjSale, J_ENTDATE as JobDate, C_CUSTOMER as CustNum FROM JOB WHERE " & strClassFilter & "J_ENTDATE >= #" & fisYrStart & "# AND J_ENTDATE < #" & fisYrEnd & "#"
        DB.RunQuery(SQL)
        pCodeTimer.EndProc("QueryYr" & i)

        pCodeTimer.StartProc("LoadYr" & i)
        fyrSalesData.LoadData(DB.DBds.Tables(0), isQuotedJob)
        pCodeTimer.EndProc("LoadYr" & i)
```

And finally "DB" in DB.Runquery etc is an instance of this DBConnection Class

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class DBConnection
'DATABASE CONNECTION
Private DBcon As New OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Z:\DATA\DATABASE\;extended properties=dbase Iv;")

Private DBcmd As OleDbCommand

'DB Data
Public DBda As OleDbDataAdapter
Public DBds As DataSet

'QUERY PARAMETERS
Public Params As New List(Of OleDbParameter)

'QUERY STATS
Public RecordCount As Integer
Public Exception As String

Dim Cnt As Integer = 0

Public Sub RunQuery(Query As String)
    Cnt += 1
    Try
        Form1.pCodeTimer.StartProc("OpenDBcon" & Cnt)
        DBcon.Open()
        Form1.pCodeTimer.EndProc("OpenDBcon" & Cnt)

        'CREATE SQL COMMAND
        Form1.pCodeTimer.StartProc("DBCreateCmd" & Cnt)
        DBcmd = New OleDbCommand(Query, DBcon)
        Form1.pCodeTimer.EndProc("DBCreateCmd" & Cnt)

        'LOAD PARAMETERS INTO OLEDB COMMAND
        Params.ForEach(Sub(x) DBcmd.Parameters.Add(x))

        'CLEAR PARAMETERS LIST
        Params.Clear()

        'EXECUTE COMMAND AND FILL DATASET
        DBds = New DataSet
        DBds.Clear()

        Form1.pCodeTimer.StartProc("DBExecuteCmd" & Cnt)
        DBda = New OleDbDataAdapter(DBcmd)
        Form1.pCodeTimer.EndProc("DBExecuteCmd" & Cnt)

        Form1.pCodeTimer.StartProc("DBFillds" & Cnt)
        RecordCount = DBda.Fill(DBds, "DB_Data")
        Form1.pCodeTimer.EndProc("DBFillds" & Cnt)
        Form1.pCodeTimer.AddDesc("DBFillds" & Cnt, "Record Count: " & RecordCount)

        DBcon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        'CAPTURE ERRORS
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Dim i As Integer = 1
    End Try

    'MAKE SURE CONNECTION IS CLOSED
    If DBcon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then DBcon.Close()

End Sub

Public Sub AddParam(Name As String, Value As Object)
    Dim NewParam As New OleDbParameter(Name, Value)
    Params.Add(NewParam)
End Sub
End Class
```

Here is a picture of the timer log (this is a "fast" load, The "DBFillds#:" is the volatile part.

[image: "Fast Load Timer Log"]

I'm well aware that I probably don't have the most elegant looking coding techniques but it works. :)

Comment: Why don't you use a simple Stopwatch?. A lot simpler and probably more precise.

Comment: Haha cause I didnt know such thing existed.  Any thoughts on the actual issue tho Steve?

Comment: No, but I think you should try the Stopwatch approach and see if it confirms your measurement.

Comment: Back in the day, I remember we had some odd performance issues with a server that turned out to be caused by the Windows NT 3D Pipes screensaver... Probably not your issue. ;-)  You could try monitoring the resource usage on the server and the network.  The best we can do is guess at the moment.

Comment: @Mark Do you know if that only affected filling a dataset? Opening the connection and running queries don't seem to have any issues, only when actually filling the dataset. I'm not 100% clear on when the data literally gets retrieved from the database but I would assume that happens prior to filling the dataset but maybe I'm wrong there.

Comment: Typically the `DataAdapter` would be running a select against the database and populating a `DataTable` named `DB_Data` in your `DataSet` `DBds` with the results, but maybe I am assuming too much.  Perhaps update your question with more complete code, so we can see how `DBda` is set up, etc.

Comment: Which database?  I've noticed that there is a noticeable delay initializing either Access/OleDB or MySQL.  I too would put little faith in a Timer, I'd also mark the time for logical parts: db aspect vs the loops and calcs

Comment: How about showing the actual query being processed..

Comment: @Plutonix it's a dbase database (.dbf File extension)